# How to create a loop for Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment?

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to make a powershell script that would list me Users list from Azure AD and all Enterprise application assigned to every user from the list.

I have tried to set ForEach-Object loop to iterate each object I would get from Get-AzureADUser

This code works:

```
$UserId = (Get-AzureADUser -Top 1).ObjectId
Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $UserId
```

I 'm trying to loop and iterate for every single output:

```
$UserId = (Get-AzureADUser).ObjectId | ForEach-Object {
Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $UserId}
```

Here is the error message:

Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ObjectId'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:44
+ Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $UserID
+                                            ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUserAppRoleAssignments

Comment: you apparently have an array in `$UserID` at that point. you are  trying  to pipe the current object ... and then you are using a $Var that is not part of the pipeline. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create the loop for Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment by these commands below:

$UserId = (Get-AzureADUser).ObjectId

foreach ($eachUserId in $UserId)
{
  Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $eachUserId
}

Comment: Could you please mark this ticket for me, thanks.@GermanMoiseenkov